# Are functions defined in CSS standard?

Tags: css, syntax, semantics

I want to know if "functions" are defined in the CSS standard; i never found a single line about them in w3schools and anywhere else.

By "function", I mean the calls like `rgb(int, int, int)` or `url(string)` that are used in CSS declarations. They look like functions, but are never called like this.

Are they names "functions" in common CSS usage, or are they just values like any other in declarations?

Comment: Actually, I'm building a CSS engine for java, and its let users register their own functions. Since I'm building an extensive documentation to the engine, I want to stick as close as possible to the CSS terminology. Thus my interrogation about functions.

Comment: They are not functions. That's just the syntax for delimiting the values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are not functions, they just look the same way as a function call. It's just a way of writing a value.

They are part of the CSS standard: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/#rgb-color

(The w3schools site is informative, but it's not complete (and occasionally incorrect or inappropriate), and it's no authority. You should look for W3C resources for the definitive documentation of the standards.)

Earlier versions of Internet Explorer would let you use expressions in CSS styles, but this was never introduced in the standards, and the support was dropped lately in IE too.

Comment: worth mentioning that the _same way as a function call_ is called a [functional notation](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#functional-notation)

Comment: Thanks, and indeed, "functional notation" is what I was looking for. I already searched the standard, but only the one for CSS1, not CSS3, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

There are some functions, which are either added or are about to be (dependend on the rendering engine).

So for example you have `calc` to dynamically determine some values, e.g.,

```
 width: calc( 100% - 3rem );
```

- [calc @mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/calc)
- [functions for css values @w3c](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#functional-notation)